# I need to install Android API 30. But I cannot see that API in the SDK platform list in Android Studio. How can I install it?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-api-30

[image]

I need to install Android API 30. But I cannot see that API in the list. How can I install it?

Comment: try checking `Hide Obsolete Packages` and `Show package Details` checkboxes.

Comment: I checked it, nothing else is showing

Comment: You're right, I can't see the older SDK too right now. I still see them a couple days ago. Seems like a bug..

Comment: ok, I've recheck my Android Studio, and sdk manager works now. It turns out that my temporary disk is full. Try checking yours.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Tools -> SDK Manager -> In the dialog check **Android 11.0 (R)** -> Download button should appear to the left, click it and download will begin.

[image]

Download button looks like this on the left:

[image]

Also check if all SDK Update Sites are checked:

[image]